# VB6 error "No creatable public component detected" after class removed

Tags: class, vb6

I'm working on a VB6 project. This project has a class which I'm no longer using. When I removed the class from the object explorer and try to compile the project again I got  the error:

[image]

> No creatable public component detected

I've checked the project's reference and components and I can't find anything to solve this issue.

Have anyone experience this before? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your removed class was probably set as the startup object. in your project click on the menu **Project |** *Project Name* **Properties** and on the **General** tab choose a new startup object.

Comment: You cannot set a class as a startup object. The choices are only `(None)`, `Sub Main` or a form in Std-EXE projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen in VB5.  I closed the dev system and then removed the .VBG file and restarted the .VBP file to force it to remake the .VBG file.  This worked.